# Define terraform object as a local so that it can be resued

Tags: terraform

Say I'm trying to create an aws backup plan as below with 2 backup rules.

```
resource "aws_backup_plan" "my_backup_plan" {
  name  = "my_backup_plan"

  rule {
    rule_name         = "daily_backup_rule"
    target_vault_name = aws_backup_vault.my-backup-vault.name
    schedule          = "cron(0 12 * * ? *)"
    lifecycle {
      delete_after    = "1"
    }
  }
  rule {
    rule_name         = "weekly_backup_rule"
    target_vault_name = aws_backup_vault.my-backup-vault.name
    schedule          = "cron(0 12 ? * 1 *)"
    lifecycle {
      delete_after    = "7"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to define the backup rule object as a local/variable and reuse the rules in multiple backup plans. It seems because this is an object rather than a map it is not possible?

```
local {
  daily_backup_rule = {
    rule_name         = "daily_backup_rule"
    target_vault_name = aws_backup_vault.my-backup-vault.name
    schedule          = "cron(0 12 * * ? *)"
    lifecycle {
      delete_after    = "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The `rule` is a block, not a map, and you can't create the blocks using your `local.daily_backup_rule`.

You could look into [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html) but then can be used to reduce the number of `rule` in one resource, instead of copy and paste them as you have now in `aws_backup_plan.my_backup_plan`.